# how to use truevfs META-INF/services on glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4, serviceloader, truevfs

Im trying to use [truevfs](https://truevfs.java.net/index.html) library from application deployed on glassfish 4. Below code works excelent if used in a standalone java-se app, but it fails to look up the filesystem provider when used from inside glassfish.

Is this suposed to work? what are my options?

The code:

```
Path uriPath = new TPath(new URI("http://localhost:8080/mytar.tar"));

try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uriPath, null)) {
    Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/");    // <-- error thrown here
    ...
}
```

The pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.truevfs</groupId>
    <artifactId>truevfs-profile-default</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and the error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Put the question to [truevfs mailing-list](https://java.net/projects/truezip/lists/users/archive/2013-11/message/6) and the author of the library answered:

> not sure if it has anything to do with that, but using 
>   FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path) is not required. Just pass the TPath
>   object  to any of the Files.* methods.

And he is right, using the [`Files.*`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) methods directly on the TPath objects worked well.